# How to add text right in the center of a flowbite carousel?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to add 2 h2 tags with text right in the vertical and horizontal center of a flowbite carousel, I cannot manage to get a good result.

My classes (for tesint):
"absolute top-500 left-500"  do not even make a difference to the way the text shows over the image. It is strange.

Here is the carousel:

```
https://flowbite.com/docs/components/carousel/
```

This is the entire html:

```
<div id="default-carousel" class="relative" data-carousel="static">
    <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
    <div class="overflow-hidden relative h-56 rounded-lg md:h-96">
         <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform translate-x-0 z-20" data-carousel-item="">
            <span class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 text-2xl font-semibold text-white -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 sm:text-3xl dark:text-gray-800">First Slide</span>
            <img src="/docs/images/carousel/carousel-1.svg" class="block absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform translate-x-full z-10" data-carousel-item="">
            <img src="/docs/images/carousel/carousel-2.svg" class="block absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="...">
        </div>
        <!-- Item 3 -->
        <div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform -translate-x-full z-10" data-carousel-item="">
            <img src="/docs/images/carousel/carousel-3.svg" class="block absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slider indicators -->
    <div class="flex absolute bottom-5 left-1/2 z-30 space-x-3 -translate-x-1/2">
        <button type="button" class="w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-white dark:bg-gray-800" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1" data-carousel-slide-to="0"></button>
        <button type="button" class="w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-white/50 dark:bg-gray-800/50 hover:bg-white dark:hover:bg-gray-800" aria-current="false" aria-label="Slide 2" data-carousel-slide-to="1"></button>
        <button type="button" class="w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-white/50 dark:bg-gray-800/50 hover:bg-white dark:hover:bg-gray-800" aria-current="false" aria-label="Slide 3" data-carousel-slide-to="2"></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Slider controls -->
    <button type="button" class="flex absolute top-0 left-0 z-30 justify-center items-center px-4 h-full cursor-pointer group focus:outline-none" data-carousel-prev="">
        <span class="inline-flex justify-center items-center w-8 h-8 rounded-full sm:w-10 sm:h-10 bg-white/30 dark:bg-gray-800/30 group-hover:bg-white/50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-800/60 group-focus:ring-4 group-focus:ring-white dark:group-focus:ring-gray-800/70 group-focus:outline-none">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-white sm:w-6 sm:h-6 dark:text-gray-800" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"></path></svg>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="flex absolute top-0 right-0 z-30 justify-center items-center px-4 h-full cursor-pointer group focus:outline-none" data-carousel-next="">
        <span class="inline-flex justify-center items-center w-8 h-8 rounded-full sm:w-10 sm:h-10 bg-white/30 dark:bg-gray-800/30 group-hover:bg-white/50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-800/60 group-focus:ring-4 group-focus:ring-white dark:group-focus:ring-gray-800/70 group-focus:outline-none">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-white sm:w-6 sm:h-6 dark:text-gray-800" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7"></path></svg>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I tried this in the first slide vua the text get stuck to the top of the slide:

```
            <div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform translate-x-0 z-20" data-carousel-item="">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/800/300/rabbit" class="block absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="">
                <div class="absolute top-500 left-500 px-4 py-2 opacity-100">
                    <h2 class="text-xl text-white font-bold text-center">Text 1 here</h3>
                    <h2 class="text-xl text-white font-bold text-center">Text 2 here</h3>
                </div>
               
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it, this seems to work perfectly, (it can be left as absolute):

```
<div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform translate-x-0 z-20" data-carousel-item="">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/300/rabbit" class="block absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="...">
    <span class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 text-2xl font-semibold text-white -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 sm:text-3xl dark:text-gray-800">First Slide</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the two h2 tags by replacing the `absolute` with `relative` for the div containing heading and adding `top-1/2` to same div.

This is the code

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="duration-700 ease-in-out absolute inset-0 transition-all transform translate-x-0 z-20" data-carousel-item="">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/800/300/rabbit" class="block  absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" alt="">
  <div class="relative top-500 top-1/2 px-4 py-2 opacity-100 ">
    <h2 class="text-xl text-white font-bold text-center ">Text 1 here</h3>
    <h2 class="text-xl text-white font-bold text-center ">Text 2 here</h3>

  </div>      
</div>
```

> Please see the full page view.

Comment: Let me try, thanks. I will post back

Comment: It seems to be working in your short example but not in the full example I have added in the question. I am wondering if the first 2 DIVs are causing problems. But they are part of the flowbite design

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes thanks but stack overflow won't let me select an answer until tomorrow, no idea why.

Comment: Okay please upvote and accept my answer. Glad I am able to help you 

Comment: The right answer is below, not above